# How do you delete a directory entry from a directory, but not delete the directorys contents?

Tags: linux

Here is the situation, I have a directory that some how ended up with entries from somewhere else in the file system.

An example:

Let's say I have a structure based on `year/month/day/`, and in that structure is have a directory `2012/01/18/normal/stuff/broken`. In the broken subdirectory there are entries (directories)

```
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12
```

These directories are the same directories that live at `/2013/`, not copies but pointers to the same inode. So `2012/01/18/normal/stuff/broken/01` has the same inode as `/2013/01`.

How does one delete the entries from `2012/01/18/normal/stuff/broken/01` without removing `/2013/01`?

Comment: They can only have the same inode if they are symbolic links. You can remove symbolic links without affecting any data.

Comment: @suspectus if they have the same inode it is is a HARD link, not a symlink. The rest of your comment is correct. You have multiple file system entries pointing to the same (data) inode. You can remove one with `rm` without a problem. Once you remove the last filename/reference, you delete the inode and data.

Comment: @sas can you explain what you mean by pointers and not copies?